# Extract values from a list of maybes

Tags: list, elm, option-type

In Elm, I have a list like:

```
[ Just a, Nothing, Just b]
```

and I want to extract from it:

```
[a, b]
```

Using List.map and pattern matching does not allow it, unless I'm wrong, because I can't return nothing when the value in the list is Nothing.
How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't want any extra dependencies, you can use [`List.filterMap`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/List#filterMap) with the [`identity`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Basics#identity) function:

```
List.filterMap identity [ Just a, Nothing, Just b ]
```

`filterMap` looks and works a lot like `map`, except the mapping function should return a `Maybe b` instead of just a `b`, and will unwrap and filter out any `Nothing`s. Using the `identity` function, will therefore effectively just unwrap and filter out the `Nothing`s without actually doing any mapping.

Alternatively, you can use [`Maybe.Extra.values`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/maybe-extra/latest/Maybe-Extra#values) from [elm-community/maybe-extra](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/maybe-extra/latest):

```
Maybe.Extra.values [ Just a, Nothing, Just b ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually in this case I use a helper function like this one:

```
extractMbVal =
    List.foldr
        (\mbVal acc ->
            case mbVal of
                Just val ->
                    val :: acc

                Nothing ->
                    acc
        )
        []
```